# How to monitor disk usage of kubernetes persistent volumes?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I have `container_fs_usage_bytes` with prometheus to monitor container root fs, but it seems that there is no metrics for other volumes in cAdvisor.

Comment: There is a ticket in the community to work on the PVC disk usage data, here is the link, fyi:
https://github.com/kubernetes/features/issues/293

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I confirmed that Kubernetes 1.8 expose metrics for prometheus.

- `kubelet_volume_stats_available_bytes`
- `kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes`
- `kubelet_volume_stats_inodes`
- `kubelet_volume_stats_inodes_free`
- `kubelet_volume_stats_inodes_used`
- `kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes`

Comment: If you use Grafana, this dashboard shows the information graphically: https://grafana.com/dashboards/6739

Comment: They no longer seem to be exposed starting from 1.12

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh Are there any new Volume usage metrics?

Comment: These metrics only only contain the information for PVCs created using the default storageclass. How can I view information for the PVCs created using other storageclasses?

Answer (score 8):

Metrics for volumes are available via the kubelet summary API (/stats/summary).  However, each volume plugin has to implement their own metrics.  As of Kubernetes 1.7, the current volume plugins that have implemented metrics include: emptydir, secrets, gce pd, aws ebs, azure file, flocker, and portworx

Comment: I don't understand what this means yet. I'll find out /stats/summary API. I'm using GKE and gce pd. Will it be available through cAdvisor and prometheus after they rolling out kubernetes 1.7 to GKE?

Answer (score 7):

The following metrics must be used for monitoring persistent volume stats in Kubernetes (the PVC name is exported in `persistentvolumeclaim` label):

- `kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes` - the per-PVC capacity in bytes.
- `kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes` - the per-PVC space usage in bytes.
- `kubelet_volume_stats_available_bytes` - the per-PVC free space in bytes.

The following [PromQL](https://valyala.medium.com/promql-tutorial-for-beginners-9ab455142085) queries can be used for determining per-pod PVC disk space usage in bytes:

```
sum(kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes) by (namespace,persistentvolumeclaim)
  * on(namespace,persistentvolumeclaim) group_left(pod)
kube_pod_spec_volumes_persistentvolumeclaims_info
```

The following query can be used for determining free PVC disk space in bytes per each pod:

```
sum(kubelet_volume_stats_available_bytes) by (namespace,persistentvolumeclaim)
  * on(namespace,persistentvolumeclaim) group_left(pod)
kube_pod_spec_volumes_persistentvolumeclaims_info
```

Comment: In my case, `kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes` only contains the metrics for PVCs created with the default storageclass (gp2). I have other PVCs attached to an efs storageclass as well. How can I view their metrics?

Comment: [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/) has no upper size limits, e.g. the `kubelet_volume_stats_available_bytes` metric cannot be defined for EFS. Probably, that's why other `kubelet_volume_stats_*` metrics aren't exported for EFS volumes.

Comment: Thank you so much! I just to mention that `kubelet_` metrics are exported by kubelet ^^ and `kube_pod_` metrics are exported by kube-state-metrics. If using kube-prometheus-stack helm chart, both components can be easily enabled.

Comment: For me `kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes` seems to contain the capacity of the underlying filesystem (local disk) and not the actual capacity defined for the volume.