# kubernetes dynamic pvc / monitoring usage

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, storage

Is there a simple way to get the current attached volume state (think "space left on disk", or the opposite) ? Using stackdriver, this info is not provided. Not to be found neither within the gcloud console. I was wondering if this was accessible besides connecting to the instance and check it manually

Comment: With "instance" do you mean the node in the kubernetes cluster or of the persistent volume attached?

Comment: The persistent volume yes

Comment: Am wondering how to make the title more accurate; thought naming pvc first would imply it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Prometeus](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus).

At the moment this option is available through Kubernetes, but merely for the 1.8 version on.
As you can check [here](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/issues/485) there is a whole topic regarding this feature request and [the code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/kubelet/server/stats/volume_stat_calculator.go#L97) that implement these features.

Kubernetes 1.8 expose metrics for prometheus.

- kubelet_volume_stats_available_bytes
- kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes
- kubelet_volume_stats_inodes
- kubelet_volume_stats_inodes_free
- kubelet_volume_stats_inodes_used
- kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes

Source [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718268/how-to-monitor-disk-usage-of-kubernetes-persistent-volumes) of the metrics.

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus, Prometheus Operator, Alertmanager and Grafana

Depending on your Kubernetes version, you may use these very easy to install setups:

Prometheus 1.x [link](https://github.com/giantswarm/kubernetes-prometheus)

Prometheus 2.x [link](https://github.com/camilb/prometheus-kubernetes)

I recommend Prometheus 2