# Monitoring Kubernetes persistent volumes usage with Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I have a K8s 1.7 cluster using **vSphere** as persistent storage provider. I have also deployed **Prometheus**, **node_exporter** and **kube-state-metrics**.

I'm trying to find a way to monitor a persistent volume's usage using **Prometheus**. I have added custom labels to some PVs, eg. `app=rabbitmq-0`, etc.

How can I combine `kube_persistentvolume_labels` with `node_filesystem_size` metrics so that I can query PV usage using my custom label?

PS.
I know that K8s 1.8 directly exposes these metrics from kubelet as mentioned in [How to monitor disk usage of kubernetes persistent volumes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44718268/how-to-monitor-disk-usage-of-kubernetes-persistent-volumes) but currently a cluster upgrade is not an option.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from (v1.3.0-rc.0 / 2018-03-23) in the **kube-state-metrics**, two metrics that can convert [PersistentVolume](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/641f44d26ccbad2272d5bf3e10e43efd41e7976d/pkg/collectors/persistentvolume.go#L128) and [PersistenVolumeClaims](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/641f44d26ccbad2272d5bf3e10e43efd41e7976d/pkg/collectors/persistentvolumeclaim.go#L151) labels to Prometheus labels accordingly were added:

```
kube_persistentvolume_labels
kube_persistentvolumeclaim_lables
```

To get more details about implementing aggregation of metrics based on labels, consider reading these articles:

- [Aggregating Pod resource (CPU, memory) usage by arbitrary labels with Prometheus](https://www.weave.works/blog/aggregating-pod-resource-cpu-memory-usage-arbitrary-labels-prometheus/)
- [Exposing the software version to Prometheus](https://www.robustperception.io/exposing-the-software-version-to-prometheus)

Answer (score 2):

There are cases when hostpath cannot be mount to pod or node will not be accessible to a project (namespace) in that case node exporter cannot be deployed, in such cases [volume_exporter](https://github.com/mnadeem/volume_exporter) would be useful.

You can just add it as a side car

```
      - name: volume-exporter
      image:  mnadeem/volume_exporter
      imagePullPolicy: "Always"
      args:
        - --volume-dir=prometheus:/prometheus
      ports:
      - name: metrics-volume
        containerPort: 9888
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /prometheus
        name: prometheus-data
        readOnly: true
```

It will generate the metrics

```
        # HELP volume_bytes_free Free size of the volume/disk
        # TYPE volume_bytes_free gauge
        volume_bytes_free{volume_name="bin",volume_path="/bin"} 4.341569536e+10
        volume_bytes_free{volume_name="etc",volume_path="/etc"} 4.341569536e+10
        # HELP volume_bytes_total Total size of the volume/disk
        # TYPE volume_bytes_total gauge
        volume_bytes_total{volume_name="bin",volume_path="/bin"} 6.391887872e+10
        volume_bytes_total{volume_name="etc",volume_path="/etc"} 6.391887872e+10
        # HELP volume_bytes_used Used size of volume/disk
        # TYPE volume_bytes_used gauge
        volume_bytes_used{volume_name="bin",volume_path="/bin"} 2.050318336e+10
        volume_bytes_used{volume_name="etc",volume_path="/etc"} 2.050318336e+10
        # HELP volume_exporter_build_info A metric with a constant '1' value labeled by version, revision, branch, and goversion from which volume_exporter was built.
        # TYPE volume_exporter_build_info gauge
        volume_exporter_build_info{branch="",goversion="go1.15",revision="",version=""} 1
        # HELP volume_percentage_used Percentage of volume/disk Utilization
        # TYPE volume_percentage_used gauge
        volume_percentage_used{volume_name="bin",volume_path="/bin"} 32.07688208958619
        volume_percentage_used{volume_name="etc",volume_path="/etc"} 32.07688208958619
```

Refer [this](https://github.com/mnadeem/volume_exporter/wiki/Running) for more details

Disclaimer : I am the owner