# How to identify the storage space left in a persistent volume claim?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, persistent-volume-claims

I have a Kubernetes cluster on Google Cloud Platform. It has a persistent Volume Claim with a Capacity of 1GB. The persistent volume claim is bound to many deployments.

I would like to identify the space left in the persistent Volume Claim in order to know if 1GB is sufficient for my application.

I have used the command "kubectl get pv" but this does not show the storage space left.

Comment: What type of PV is it?

Comment: The storageClassName is networkvolume if that is what you are referring to

Comment: Is it NFS? or something else?

Comment: It is not NFS. It is a persistent volume claim

Comment: A PV has a type: [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#types-of-persistent-volumes). That's what @Rico is asking.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If there's a running pod with mounted PV from the PVC,

```
kubectl -n <namespace> exec <pod-name> -- df -ah
```

...will list all file systems, including the mounted volumes, and their free disk space.

Comment: FYI - this does not work if the container does not have the `df` command installed (like many prod containers). Is there another way?

Comment: kubectl exec <pod-name> -- df -h

Comment: FYI this doesn't work if the pod cannot start due to an error (which might be a full disk)

Comment: Yes, @peetasan. As the answer states: "...If there's a running pod with mounted PV from the PVC..."

Comment: This does not show the used space of the PVC volume claim and instead list the space from the host node

Answer (score 30):

You can monitorize them with kubelet prometheus metrics:

```
kubelet_volume_stats_available_bytes{persistentvolumeclaim="your-pvc"}
kubelet_volume_stats_capacity_bytes{persistentvolumeclaim="your-pvc"}
```

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work with GP3 volumes as of today :/ see https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/issues/816

Comment: 'kubelet_volume_stats_used_bytes' see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47117776/1747983

Answer (score 20):

I wrote a [script](https://gist.github.com/redmcg/60cfff7bca6f32969188008ad4a44c9a) that lists all the PVCs in a cluster in a format similar to `df`.

You can run it via:

`./kubedf`

or:

`./kubedf -h`

for a human readable output.

Edit: The script no longer requires `kubectl proxy` to be running

Answer (score 9):

Adding to @apisim's answer if you add -h parameter then you can get details in human readable format. Something like this,

```
kubectl -n <namespace> exec <pod-name> -- df -h
```

[image]

Comment: To see pseudo filesystems should be `df -ah`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NFS:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ncdu
cd /your_nfs/kubernetes/
sudo ncdu .
```

```
ncdu 1.12 ~ Use the arrow keys to navigate, press ? for help
--- /your_nfs/kubernetes/ ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   34.1 GiB [##########] /backups
    2.1 GiB [          ] /redis
    1.9 GiB [          ] /XXX
  785.5 MiB [          ] /postgresql
  435.7 MiB [          ] /XXX
  391.2 MiB [          ] /XXX
```

Press `C` to see number/count of files.